# Vector Auto Regressive model is significant when all IVs are run together, but not significant if model is run separately for each IV

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I have 10 (many more available) independent variables (IV) and one dependent variable (DV). I do not have specific hypotheses to test but am using an exploratory approach to find the IVs that can explain the DV. I am running a vector auto-regressive (VAR) model. When I run the DV on each IV separately, only one of the IVs is significant. However, when I run the DV on all of the 10 IVS in a single model, 3 of them turn out to be significant.

I would understand if it were the other way round: If some IVs were significant when run separately but not when run together, I would understand that there may be some collinearity going on among them, and the fact that the model may partial out the overlapping variances may lead to some IVs to lose significance in presence of other IVs. But my case is the opposite. I was expecting any IV that is significant when run in a group of IVs in a single model to be significant when run on its own, given the fact that there is not interaction effect tested in VAR.

Can someone please explain potential reasons?

Comment: Do you have a theoretical reason to test the IVs separately or all together? You should be testing a hypothesis.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. No, I do not have a specific hypothesis to test. I have about 110 economic time series, which can all be adequately modeled as AR(1)s. I'm using VAR as an exploratory tool to help me narrow my analysis down to those economic series that have causal relationship with the DV (an asset price AR(1) series). What do you say?

Comment: It's far outside of the norm for my field, but you might try a longitudinal hierarchical linear model with an AR(1) level one error term in a stepwise manner. However this leaves me feeling uneasy, like it's bordering on dishonesty, but then again I'm an educator, not an economist.

Comment: Why are you using a VAR model if you only have one dependent variable? A VAR model requires several dependent variables that affect each other. Otherwise you may use an AR model with exogenous regressors and their lags.

Comment: @RichardHardy; based on the second sentence of this source (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/79), I tend to believe that a VAR model tests the possible set of causal relationships among the series fed into the model. So, it does not practically matter which series is DV or IV based on theory. This is congruent with the statsmodels' VAR model's output. The fed series take turn to act as DVs and IVs. So, if you fed the model 3 series, it runs the model for three separate equations, each having one of the series as the DV. Can you kindly refer me to a source on what you said?

Comment: @RichardHardy: this link (http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) seems to reinforce what you were saying. The author states that "Rather than declare the lag interval for the 2 endogenous variables to be from 1 to 7 (the latter being p + m), I'm going to leave the interval at 1 to 6, and declare the extra (7th.) lag of each variable to be an "exogenous" variable." I'm a bit confused thought. While the author's Eviews program allows to specify a VAR with Exogenous variables (see the image on the link), statsmodels' VAR does not. Please advise.

Comment: @Saeed, since all variables in a VAR model get to be the left-hand-side variable (one in each equation), none of them is independent (because they are determined within the model) by the definition of independence. This should be found in any decent text on VAR models. This is also in line with what you said, except that your use of terms "independent" and "dependent" seems to be different from the classical meaning of these words within the VAR model literature. Regarding implementation in Stata, I do not know, I do not use Stata.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks a lot for the explanation. So, to sum, if I have a large number of AR(p) time series and want to see which ones cause another AR(p) time series of interest, I should use ARX?

Comment: @RichardHardy, forgive me for keeping adding info here. What I am trying to do is figuring out which of the 100s of economic time series available in fact cause stock market performance. I'd like to narrow my predictor variable universe to those with causal effect on stock market performance to be able to further investigate their causal relationship.

Comment: Technically you can investigate the effects of lagged variables on one variable of interest either in ARX or in VAR framework. ARX is in a sense "necessary and sufficienty" whereas VAR is "sufficient "but not "necessary" because it has many equations that you will not use. You will only use one of them. If you extract that one equation from the VAR model, you obtain the ARX model. Choose whichever way is more convenient; sometimes it can be more convenient (quicker to code) to run a VAR and just ignore all equations but one.

Comment: It's good to hear that you said a VAR model can be seen as a collection of ARX model. As you said, running VAR is just easier for me. So, I'll stick with it. Thanks for all your advice, Richard.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned collinearity and that is the main reason why variables can be insignificant on their own, but significant when included with others. [This post provides a good explanation as to why.](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_in_regression_analysis_does_the_inclusion_of_a_new_variable_makes_other_variables_that_previously_were_not_statistically_significant)

One thing that could be happening is a manifestation of Simpson's paradox. With correlated variables, Simpson's paradox can

1. Make variables, which are insignificant on there own, significant only when considered with other variables.
2. Make variables, which are significant on there own, insignificant when considered with other variables.

Other things can happen too (like changing the direction of effects), but I'll concentrate on these two for your question and give examples with pictures. In the pictures, $x_1$ is a continuous variable and $x_2$ is categorical with two levels A and B.

The first figure is an example of 1.

[image]

When $x_1$ is considered on its own, there is no effect. But there is a strong effect of $x_1$ within each level of $x_2$. Thus the effect of $x_1$ is only revealed after conditioning on $x_2$ (or including $x_2$ in the model as well).

The second figure is an example of 2.

[image]

Now, when conditioning on $x_2$ the effect of $x_1$ goes away.

In both cases, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated - given $x_1$ I can predict $x_2$ and vice versa.

---

Two more examples with equations are given below:

Consider a linear regression relationship:

$y = x_1 - x_2 +\epsilon $

Where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are highly correlated ($x_1\approx x_2$). This means, on its own $y\approx \epsilon$ or just completely random. Scatterplots of $y$ vs. $x_1$ and $y$ vs $x_2$ would not reveal a relationship and so fitting the separate regressions would likely result in insignificant effects. However, if you get the model right and adjust for each variable, there is a good chance both $x_1$ and $x_2$ would be significant.

For a simulation to demonstrate:

````
``` r
n <- 100
set.seed(123)
x1 <- runif(n, -1, 1)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1)

y <- x1 - x2 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1)

summary(fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                 Estimate  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.006885841 0.6257851
#> x1          -0.001069447 0.9657164
summary(fit2 <- lm(y ~ x2))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                 Estimate  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.006628779 0.6359151
#> x2          -0.031507289 0.1991129
summary(fit12 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                 Estimate     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.001039833 9.122997e-01
#> x1           1.079152018 1.491989e-18
#> x2          -1.085095244 6.533089e-19
```
````

We can see that x1 and x2 only become significant when considered together. Note - it can cut both ways (as per your intuition), but it depends on the nature of the relationship. As an example:

````
``` r
n <- 100
set.seed(123)
x1 <- runif(n, -1, 1)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1)

y <- x1 + 0.01 * x2 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1)

summary(fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                Estimate     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 0.001444412 8.779604e-01
#> x1          1.004394069 1.441806e-79
summary(fit2 <- lm(y ~ x2))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                Estimate     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 0.006628779 6.359151e-01
#> x2          0.978492711 1.177180e-62
summary(fit12 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2))$coefficients[, c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
#>                 Estimate     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.001039833 9.122997e-01
#> x1           1.079152018 1.491989e-18
#> x2          -0.075095244 4.452773e-01
```
````

Now the variables are both significant individually, but $x_2$ loses its significance when considered with $x_1$. In reallity $x_2$ has a small effect but when considered individually it looks like $x_1$ which has a larger effect. Together $x_2$'s effect is dominated by $x_1$ and harder to tease out.

Comment: It can actually work both ways - and depends on the nature of the relationship. I have edited my response to demonstrate.

Comment: I have now included examples with pictures to demonstrate how correlation between variables can cause both situations.